# Developing to all devices

Tags: android

Is there any way with the Android SDK to emulate a specific device ROM?  For example, could I launch an emulator that replicated the Verizon Droid Incredible, or the Sprint HTC Hero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a way to say make my emulator be a Droid. However, you can create an avd with many of the features of the different phones: sdk versions, screen sizes, disk space, etc.  See [avd documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) for details.  For most applications, as long as you test against a few different sdk levels and screen sizes you should be ok.